# Why I must have a default constructor in a Spring configuration class annoted by the @Configuration annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, applicationcontext

I am studying for Spring Core certification and, on the provided study stuff, I have this question but I can't give an answer to it.

> Why must you have to have a default constructor in your @Configuration
>   annotated class?

I don't declare any constructor into my configuration classes annoted by the **@Configuration** annotation. The default constructor is the one inherited by the super class? or what? Why I must have a default constructor and I can't override it?

Tnx

Comment: Guess it means you need a constructor without parameters. So you can override constructor but it need a constructor without parameters to create the Configuration.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to [official spring javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html), spring @Configuration annotated classes are required to have default no-arg constructor

> @Configuration classes must have a default/no-arg constructor and may not use @Autowired constructor parameters. Any nested configuration classes must be static

The reason is that spring uses [CGLIB to proxy @Configuration](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/cglib-is-required-to-process-configuration-classes/) classes and there is limitation in Spring, [that classes proxied with CGLIB prior to version 4 are required to have default no-args constructor](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/07/spring-4-cglib-based-proxy-classes-with-no-default-ctor.html).

> Prior to Spring 4, CGLIB-based proxy classes require a default constructor. And this is not the limitation of CGLIB library, but Spring itself. Fortunately, as of Spring 4 this is no longer an issue. CGLIB-based proxy classes no longer require a default constructor.

Comment: I have already read the documentation but it only say that class annoted with @Configuration require a default no-arg constructor but don't explain why

Comment: Default constructors imo are a cause of bad design, since it forces objects to be mutable - by requiring setters for properties. I steer away from Spring magic annotations, and try to keep all Spring dependencies in a package that contain all my config files, and I control all my dependencies and the IoC in there in an explicit manner.

Comment: This is a really old answer but perhaps you can still help. I am still seeing "Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given" when trying to create a proxy, even though I am on Spring 4.x. I thought that default constructors were no longer mandatory.

Comment: Spring 5.* doesn't require no-args default constructor.